# Why we ignore the negative value of time?

Tags: kinematics, projectile

solving a quadratic equation we get two values of $x$ 
in calculating time for different numericals. a positive and a negative value comes.why we ignore the negative value? some logical answer except time cant be negative?

Comment: Because we are more interested in knowing where the projectile actually will land than,  in knowing where it hypothetically could have come from?

Answer (score 3):

The negative value corresponds to when in the past that object would have had the same position that you're considering in the future.  With the quadratic equation, the object will pass most points once "going up" and once "going down".  The negative solution gives you the one that's in the past, which is a valid solution as long as you are asking a question about the past.  But usually our questions are phrased about what will happen in the future.